# Data persistence with reusable cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, mvvm

I have a large table designed to update a customers data protection preferences.

Some of the table is populated with reusable cells that contain a variable number of checkboxes, and depending on the json returned from the server, some of these checkboxes may be pre-checked.

When I pass the pre-checked state to the cell from tableView cellForRowAt all is well (checkboxes that are pre-checked are pre-checked). The problem I have is that these are reusable cells, and after a user has changed their selections, scrolling up or down the table triggers more calls to the setupCell function, which then resets the checkboxes to their original pre-checked state.

So, the question I have is...

**What are the options for me to preserve a user’s selections after they have scrolled a table with resuable cells?**

The switch statement in setupCell currently sets the pre-selections with the call to updateSelections(). Obviously this is the cause of the issue and I'm not entirely happy with placing logic directly in the cell anyway, but where is the best place to perform this logic only once? Or, is using reusable cells the wrong approach entirely to have pre-selections?

Any suggestions welcome. Here's a small code snippet to illustrate the point:

```
// UITableViewDataSource - passing the previous selections to setupCell in the UITableViewCell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let viewModel = viewModels[indexPath.row]
    switch viewModel {
    case .preferences(let preferenceId, let titleText, let isEnabled):
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Preferences") as? MarketingChannelPreferencesTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.setupCell(id: id, text: text, isPreChecked: isPreChecked)
        return cell
    }
}

// UITableViewCell    
func setupCell(id: String, text: String, isPreChecked: Bool) {
    switch id {
    case "email":
        emailSelected = isPreChecked
        updateSelections(id: id, isPreChecked: emailSelected)
    case "post":
        postSelected = isPreChecked
        updateSelections(id: id, isPreChecked: postSelected)
    case "text":
        textSelected = isPreChecked
        updateSelections(id: id, isPreChecked: textSelected)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

viewModels hold the information needed to setup each cell right? And you receive the viewModels from the service?

If so, when the user changes a specific checkbox, you should update the according viewModel. Thus, when you call `setupCell` inside `cellForRowAt` you should pass the updated info of each viewModel, resulting in the correct state of each checkbox.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately (for me) I came to that conclusion shortly after posting the question! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should make some action method for your checkbox buttons that you put on the MarketingChannelPreferencesTableViewCells and change your viewModels based on changing the value of these checkboxes. So when the cells data reload with user scrolling, cells show the new datas of viewModel

Answer (score 0):

There're several ways.
I've created a small project maybe it will give you an solution to the problem.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d_RFdr6luNvRTdSC6XNE2vRWTi2IRyuT

Comment: https://github.com/invinciible/PreserveTableViewSelectionExample now check